# How to resolve excessive CPU usage?

Tags: 13.04, cpu, ram-usage

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my brand new notebook and PU usage is insane. I'm a new Linux user. Can somebody help me?

Specs and system monitor:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are using an AMD C-70 DualCore with a 1.3 GHz clock. That is not very much CPU power. And a chrome instance can easily use it entirely.

If you want to know which program is using your CPU the most switch to the 'Processes' tab ('procesos') and sort by '% CPU'.

If it is chrome you can use its inbuild taskmanager (shortcut shift + escape) to view which tab/extension is t